# Is there any difference between tv and TV?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I thought the abbreviation of television was TV, but I read an article where the author used italic *tv*. Given the article is about the author's love for games, I am wondering whether *tv* is used to refer to the screen of gaming systems. Or there is no difference between *tv* and TV.

> When I take stock of the collection I’ve accrued over the past eight years – hunting down classic games on road trips, reporting trips and vacations – what else is there to think about but the shame of it: the wasted hours on “Final Fantasy III” and “Super Metroid”, the winters alone in my bedroom sitting close enough to the ***tv*** to kiss it, the football games and parties that I missed?

Comment: TV is so well known that it's sometimes written in lowercase and is still understood by all.

Comment: The [vast majority of writers](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=watched+tv%2Cwatched+TV&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) capitalise TV, but it's of no consequence if someone *doesn't*.

Comment: As an English teacher, I'd mark "tv" incorrect for not being capitalized.

Comment: I believe the increasing use of lowercase tv can be related to the use of the .tv domain for television and video related content.  Use of lowercase letters in domain names is standard practice, even though they are technically case-insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, TV should always be capitalized. If I am writing in an informal setting such as a text message, I would likely leave it lowercase. Writing it in italics does not change the meaning, and appears to just be an unusual choice on the part of the original author.

Italics are used to emphasize something that is important or to make it clear that something is a title, but they do not generally change the meaning of a word.

Comment: Italics are also employed in the use-mention distinction: Many is the time I have dreamed I could fly, but *many* appears to be cognate with Russian *много*.